# Add margins to each Column

Tags: php

How do I add margin to each of the column that will be echoed such that they are aligned uniformly ie. each column in every row should begin exactly where the previous one begins.

[// (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) - //(ignore this line)]

Here is my code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="docfullcss.css">

<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $dbname = 'employee_info';

    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

    if(! $conn ) 
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    } 

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `docfull` ORDER BY `COL 7` ASC';

    $retval = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    if(! $retval ) 
    {
        die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    }



    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQLI_ASSOC))  
    {
        echo $row['COL 1'];
        echo "&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp";
        echo $row['COL 2'];
        echo "&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp";

        echo $row['COL 3'];
        echo "&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp";
        echo $row['COL 4'];
        echo "&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp";

        echo $row['COL 5'];
        echo "&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp";
        echo $row['COL 6'];
        echo "&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp";

        echo $row['COL 7'];
        echo "&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp";
        echo $row['COL 8'];
        echo "&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp";

        echo $row['COL 9'];
        echo "&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp";
        echo $row['COL 10'];
        echo "&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp";

        echo $row['COL 11'];
        echo "&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp";
        echo $row['COL 12'];
        echo "&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp";

        echo $row['COL 13'];
        echo "&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp";
        echo $row['COL 14'];
        echo "&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp";

        echo $row['COL 15'];
        echo "&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp";
        echo $row['COL 16'];
        echo "&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp";
         echo "<br><br>";

    }  

      mysqli_close($conn); 
?>
```

Comment: use <table> to set format.

Comment: Do I have to format in CSS or does <table> have its own parameters for text align ?

Comment: table will set columns on same line with same margin in every row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best thing to do is, using a table. Check out below code.

```
echo "<table>";

    echo "<thead>";

    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<th>YOUR HEADING 1</th>";
    echo "<th>YOUR HEADING 2</th>";
    echo "<th>YOUR HEADING 3</th>";
    echo "<th>YOUR HEADING 4</th>";
    echo "<th>YOUR HEADING 5</th>";
    echo "<th>YOUR HEADING 6</th>";
    echo "<th>YOUR HEADING 7</th>";
    echo "<th>YOUR HEADING 8</th>";

    echo "</tr>";

    echo "</thead>";

    echo "<tbody>";


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQLI_ASSOC))  
        {
            echo "<tr>";

            echo "<td>";
            echo $row['COL 1'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $row['COL 2'];
            echo "</td>";

            echo "<td>";
            echo $row['COL 3'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $row['COL 4'];
            echo "</td>";

            echo "<td>";
            echo $row['COL 5'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $row['COL 6'];
            echo "</td>";

            echo "<td>";
            echo $row['COL 7'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $row['COL 8'];
            echo "</td>";

            echo "</tr>";

        }  

        echo "</tbody>";

        echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Is there a way to Increase the margin width from COL 7 onwards?

Comment: Can you please clarify. I think you're asking to increase the padding. If that so, simply add a class to the "<td>" elements starting from 7 and onwards. As an example

echo "<td class='increased_padding_of_td'>";
echo $row['COL 7'];
echo "</td>";

then, with css,

.increased_padding_of_td {
      padding: 20px; /* You may add a value you want */
}

Hope it's clear to you.
Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
# start table
echo '<table border="1">';

echo '<thead>';
echo '<th>';                 # start heading
echo '<td>COL 1</td>';
echo '<td>COL 2</td>';
# ... up to 16 columns
echo '</th>';               # end heading
echo '</thead>';

echo '<tbody>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQLI_ASSOC))  
{
    # start row
    echo '<tr>'                             

    # add cell ie column
    echo  '<td>' . $row['COL 1'] . '</td>';
    echo  '<td>' . $row['COL 2'] . '</td>';
    # ... up to 16 columns

    # end row
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</tbody>';

// end table
echo '</table>';
```